# How to deal with IEnumerables/Arrays/Collections in Fluxor State?

Tags: c#, blazor, fluxor

I'm currently trying to implement Fluxor for my Blazor WASM app and all the instructions/tutorials I found recommended something like this example for the Store:

```
public record AppStore {
   int ClickCounter,
   bool IsLoading,
   WeatherForecast[]? Forecasts
}
```

and then only talk about initial state and updates only happen to the `bool` and the `int` while the array is only ever *replaced* outright. I.e. the examples always fetch the complete data from the server, e.g. a 100 entries.

Now, here's my question: How do I properly deal with the array in my reducer when I have already 100 entries in there and only want do add/update/delete *one*? Is that even a good idea in the first place?

Comment: Your reducer should produce new state based on the incoming state and the action that is being applied to the state. So if you have an input array, you can modify that state (including removing a single item) and generating a new state. That said, you only show a store and your store in turn should contain states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use `ImmutableList<T>` or `ImmutableArray<T>` instead, as this class is optimised for the purpose of returning a new instance that includes old data but without having to copy the elements.

I've recently released a new library called `Reducible` that helps to create complex state reducers. It results in fewer updates (e.g. a new parent object isn't created if an item in the list is not replaced).

https://github.com/mrpmorris/Reducible/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you. That was the thing I was searching for.

Comment: @Rhywden see updated answer